# What will be the appropriate separator?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file which has below structure:

```
>hsa:9934 K04299 purinergic receptor P2Y, G protein-coupled
MINSTSTQPPDESCSQNLLITQQIIPVLYCMVFIAGILLNGVSGWIFFYVPSSKSFIIYL
KNIVIADFVMSLTFPFKILGDSGLGPWQLNVFVCRVSAVLFYVNMYVSIVFFGLISFDRY
>hsa:9934 K04299 purinergic receptor P2Y, G protein-coupled
MINSTSTQPPDESCSQNLLITQQIIPVLYCMVFIAGILLNGVSGWIFFYVPSSKSFIIYL
KNIVIADFVMSLTFPFKILGDSGLGPWQLNVFVCRVSAVLFYVNMYVSIVFFGLISFDRY
```

I need to load and convert this file as below tabular structure:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
|>hsa:9934 K04299 purinergic receptor P2Y, G protein-coupled |
|MINSTSTQPPDESCSQNLLITQQIIPVLYCMVFIAGILLNGVSGWIFFYVPSSKSFIIYL|
|KNIVIADFVMSLTFPFKILGDSGLGPWQLNVFVCRVSAVLFYVNMYVSIVFFGLISFDRY|
--------------------------------------------------------------
|>hsa:9934 K04299 purinergic receptor P2Y, G protein-coupled |
|MINSTSTQPPDESCSQNLLITQQIIPVLYCMVFIAGILLNGVSGWIFFYVPSSKSFIIYL|
|KNIVIADFVMSLTFPFKILGDSGLGPWQLNVFVCRVSAVLFYVNMYVSIVFFGLISFDRY|
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried below code:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv(path, sep = ">")
```

But it doesn't worked as I expected!

How can I get the exact format?

Comment: I'm not clear about your problem.  It appears that your reading requirement is a simple line-based text input.

Comment: Do you want to create a DataFrame or a new text file?

Comment: @Prune, it is a multiline based text input.

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski I want to create a DataFrame.

Comment: My problem is solved now. Thanks all of you. :)

Answer (score 2):

you could use str.split('>') so you end up with an array for each value.
Unless '>' might appear in the hashes

Comment: to further add to this, if you're guaranteed that `hsa` will always be present, then you could split on `>hsa`.

Comment: @oneindelijk,  Your solution not worked as I expected, But it brings me to the solution. 

A big Thanks! :)